# Is it possible to integrate Mouse scroll events in Anylogic (in GIS space) to change the size of agents relative to the map size?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

In anylogic, I am using GIS environment for my project model, there I am able to change the size of my agents relative to the map size in GIS using buttons, (zoomIn and zoomOut). However the task is achieved but its not a practical method. I want to improve it and want to change the size change of my agents in GIS environment relative to the map size using Java mouse scroll events, is it possible to acive it using mouseEvents in anylogic 8.5 or above? any idea would be highly appriciated thank you in advance.

I have used buttons and i achieved it with buttons but i didn't like it.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do much because anylogic doesn't give you access when you move the map or when you use mouse scroll on the map what the current zoom level is or where the current position of the map is... AnyLogic loses this information when you interact with the map.

Also, AnyLogic doesn't give you access to mouse interactions unless they are explicit (on click action on an object).

Unfortunately even though it's true that zoom in and zoom out buttons are not practical, they are the best you can do.